# Getting black screen when using CCLayerPanZoom instead of CCLayer

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

To be able to pan and zoom some of the content in screen I decided to use CCLayerPanZoom extension. When I look at the source code I can see that it derives from the CCLayer class. So I change the parent class of the node that's pushed to the navigation stack from CCLayer to CCLayerPanZoom. But what I get when the app launches is just a black screen. To make it cleaner, I created a new class, derived it from CCLayerPanZoom, added a test sprite onto it in the init method and pushed it to the navigation stack in the AppDelegate.m. Still I got nothing, just a black screen. Here're the two methods that I've implemented in my class:

```
@interface TestPanZoom : CCLayerPanZoom {

}
+(CCScene *) scene;
@end

@implementation TestPanZoom
+(CCScene *) scene
{
    // 'scene' is an autorelease object.
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

    // 'layer' is an autorelease object.
    TestPanZoom *layer = [TestPanZoom node];

    // add layer as a child to scene
    [scene addChild: layer];

    // return the scene
    return scene;
}

-(id)init{
    if(self=[super init])
    {
        CCSprite *sprite=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Default.png"];
        sprite.scale=0.5;
        [self addChild:sprite];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```